# C#: Visual 2008 code to UML diagram

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, uml

I have code a Visual 2008 project. It have finished.

Now, my customer want document includes UML diagrams.

So, Can i switch automatically these code to UML something like class diagram or sequence diagram?

Comment: the programming scenario is write program using UML not in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

You can create class diagram out of existing code quite easily.  Here is a good link to MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff657806.aspx

Right-click on the project node in the solution explorer and add a new item.  Choose Class Diagram.  You can now drag class files onto the designer.  You can arrange them, and show property->type associations.